# How to add .ini file type to the plugin editor to read and edit?

Tags: plugin-development

Referring to `/wp-admin/plugin-editor.php`

The plugin editor does not include `.ini` files and I use that file type in a plugin to create dynamic message constants. I want to be able to edit that file via the editor.

I explored `wp_doc_link_parse()` but to no avail.

#### How can I add file types to the allowed list?

Comment: Hmm... The question is a bit broad. It's like if I asked: "How can I buy an apple". There are a bazillion ways I can do it, but maybe only a couple of the answers are relevant to my setup and situation. Therefore... Can you elaborate a bit on, what you have tried and what errors you get, when you do so? And welcome to the forum! I hope we can figure out the pickle you're in. :-)

Comment: @Zeth The question was **clearly understood and accurately answered** by Paul G, therefore there's no need for me to "elaborate a bit". Since you know of "bazillion ways [you] can do it", feel free to post them all.

Comment: I didn't mean to step on anybodies toes. I'm glad that Paul G guessed which challenge you were facing. I was simply trying to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code below should work if you add it to your `functions.php` in your theme:

```php
add_filter( 'editable_extensions', function ( $default_types ) {
    $default_types[] = 'ini';
    return $default_types;
} );
```

Assumptions:

- You're using at least PHP 5.3
- You're using at least WordPress 4.9